# Sending new configuration to an ESP8266 over local network

Tags: electron, esp8266, esp8266wifi

My esp8266 is running a code that creates an access point so the user can enter it's IP address and connect the esp to the local network. After the device is connected, its access point is turned off and it sends an UDP Package to the local network with its unique identifier. That's the basic setup.
I've been developing an Electron desktop app that can listen to this udp package and identify the device. So far so good.
Now I would like to make my electron app be able to flash any configuration I want to the device over local network. It must be able to keep the basic setup and flash some new features like turning on lights or sending infrared commands to other devices.

All I can find on the internet is about the ArduinoOTA library, but it allows the user to flash configuration using the access point interface. I would like to have the AP mode off after it is connected to the local wifi and send configuration over the local network. Is that possible?

Comment: the ArduinoOTA doesn't use the SoftAP. it is for upload from IDE. you may want to use the ESP8266HTTPUpdateServer library